Why does this oddly nice lognormal shape come out of tree?
I was reading this paper and came across the Euclid tree. For a simple version of this tree, consider an infinite binary tree rooted with the triple $(1,2,3)$. Then for each vertex $(x,y,z)$, its left child is $(x, z, x + z)$ and its right child is $(y, z, y + z)$. I plotted the tree below:

Some facts about the Euclid tree:

All triples are off the form $(a, b, a+b)$ so the largest entry is the last one, which I will call the height of the triple.
If we look at the heights of the tree, every height $h$ shows up exactly $\varphi(h)/2$ times.

When I graphed the heights of the triples on each layer on a histogram, I noticed a nice lognormal distribution shape forming (shown below):

Does anyone have any insight as to why the distribution of heights tends to this shape? (Also, can anyone approximate the pdf/cdf of this?)

Don't you mean left children are $(x, z, x + z)$ instead of $(x, y, x + z)$?

I looked at something like this once, the children of $(x,y,z)$ were $(y,z,x+z)$ and $(y,z,y+z)$, with $(1,1,1)$ at the root. I found that there were six small (positive) integers never show up in the tree, the smallest was $23$. I forget what the largest was, maybe $730$, but certainly three digits.

Somewhat reminds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number#Markov_tree
